# Enabling test configuration and overriding config in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Currently I'm working in a project which interacts with PubSub but I want it to also work with `TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration` (executing tests without going to Google to retrieve the credentials).

```
spring.profiles.active= pubsub

spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=test

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination= output-queue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination= input-queue
```

By default, all the `AutoConfiguration` classes related to Google are included within the `exclude` property in `@SpringBootApplication`

However I've noticed that if the parent `application.properties` properties has some of the properties that I want to override, the application classes are still instantiated with those instead of the overriden ones, meaning that I'm trying to use TestSupportBinder classes with PubSub ones.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyProcessor.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "--spring.profiles.active="
})
```

Is there any workaround for this? So that the main classes are configured with the newly overriden properties instead of gathering configs from different places in tests and main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively you're describing integration (with google) vs. unit testing (without google). Typically we separate the two. For example we have a separate integration module https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream-integration-tests and also Rabbit and Kafka are themselves in the separate modules for it's own integration testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Oleg! So you would say that having a "common" parent module implementing the application that is going to be deployed with a given config for it and then creating separate modules which depend on the parent one with another `application.properties` and specific classes so that tests are developed within is the way to go?

Comment: something like that, yes